# Need to do API calls on Array of data and get the response Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, api, http, rxjs

I want to implement a logic where if there is no network connectivity then i am storing the data in frontend in local storage and whenever got connected to network then I want to do api call on the this array of data from local storage. And if call is success then remove this item from storage and continue the process until done.

I have tried many ways using promise.all and forkJoin. Can anybody suggest the proper way to do it.

Comment: also, look at service workers for this . They are used for similar problems 


but on high level u can create another wrapper around your api call which does something like this 

`apiCall()
.then( // return this data  and update the array)
.catch( // check if network issue , then return from array else keep throwing the error )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the above question:

```
 makeHttpCalls(elements: any[]): Observable<any[]> {
if (this.network.type === 'none') {
  console.log('No network connection');
  return of(null);
}
const requests = elements.map(element => this.http.post(element.url, element.data));
return forkJoin(requests).pipe(
  map(responses => {
    return elements.filter((element, index) => !responses[index].success);
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return of(null);
  })
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple approach. Firstly, you have to check if there is a network connection then you have to decide whether you have to store data in local storage or make an `http` call.

You can get the internet connection status via this `navigator.onLine`

So let me give you a sample approach. Let's say you have a function to save customer data. So you can have like this

```
addCustomer(customerObject: Customer){
  if(navigator.onLine){
    // make api call
    this.http.post('www.api-server.com/api/v1/customers', customerObject);
    localStorage.setItem('customers', JSON.stringify([]));
  } else {
    let localCustomersData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customers'));
    localCustomersData.push(customerObject);
    localStorage.setItem('customers',JSON.stringify(localCustomersData));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Harish & Fahad. Thanks for giving your opinion. I really appreciate it.  I have sorted out the checking network part and storing it in storage already. But, I am trying to figure out the best approach in which I can do http call on array of data and get the response in Angular, if it was successful then remove from array.

Comment: Can you please include some code ?

Comment: Can you share your solution please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use online and offline listeners to run your functions which does set the list.
when you want to add an item to list, you check if there is an active network connection. which is possible by looking at `navigator.onLine`.

which is explained in  [fahad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74995347/3964849). when back online, to process the offline list, you can use event listeners to go through list and process the item.

`addEventListener('online', (event) => processOffilineList());` with this you can create a listener that's triggered when you're online and the function can find the list from local storage and process the list.